# Avoiding memory leak from crittercism in android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, crittercism, leakcanary

We use crittercism in our app for crash reporting.  We've recently began using LeakCanary, and the app is finding leaks which appear to be caused by crittercism.  Does anyone know of a way to configure or manipulate crittercism's android SDK to avoid this leak?

```
* com.my.app.activity.MyActivity has leaked:
* GC ROOT com.my.app.AppInstance.mActivityLifecycleCallbacks
* references java.util.ArrayList.array
* references array java.lang.Object[].[1]
* references crittercism.android.av.g
* references crittercism.android.bd.mPendingResult
* references android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.this$0
* references android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.mContext
* leaks com.my.app.activity.MyActivity instance

* Device: motorola motorola XT1254 quark_verizon
* Android Version: 4.4.4 API: 19 LeakCanary: 1.3.1
* Durations: watch=6008ms, gc=210ms, heap dump=3730ms, analysis=29858ms
```

Comment: What is `com.my.app.AppInstance`?

Comment: What version of the Crittercism SDK?

Comment: we're using com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:5.0.6

Comment: @CommonsWare AppInstance is the class which extends Application for my app.

Comment: Have you tried filing a support ticket with them? And have you tried using Crittercism Android SDK 5.2.0?

Comment: I am having same problem on Android 4.1.2 Samsung

Comment: Have you fixed it somehow? Is there any workaround for it?